# If I'm localising an app, should I localise the app's app store title too?

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

I've noticed that quite a few apps don't (big ones mainly).

Does anyone have any experience doing/not doing this? If you haven't localised your app's title, has the localisation still improved your number of downloads?

For example, say my app was called "Month Planner" - what would the pros and cons of translating this be?

Comment: Translating titles generally sounds unprofessional. Only stock Apple apps do that (i. e. the default utilities that come with iOS), but they have a good reason for that. I don't suggest you translate the title from English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a programming question so I doubt it should be here, but... you are talking about branding. Naming your app as something recognizable as the app. "Month Planner" is not a good name for an app, it is a description of what the app does.
You want your app to have a single global name, so when a user searches "MyApp Name" it doesn't matter what the language is, your app will be found.

So do:

- Give your app a unique name
- Localize app descriptions

Don't:

- Give your app a generic function name in English or some other language.
- Change the name of your app based on location (unless you want different brands in different places, but that's another kettle of fish).

Avoid:

- Generic, obvious or dictionary names. It'll only end in trouble when your brand collides with that of someone else (see [Apple Corps v Apple Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Corps_v_Apple_Computer) for a famous example).